# How to get status information form xinetd

Tags: xinetd

How can I get some status information from xinetd, for example which servers are running/listening, which connections are open at the moment and so on. I found some hints which say "normally every server has an own file in /etc/xinet.d/*", but I don't wont to image the information, I want to see it :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send SIGUSR1 to xinetd (`pkill -USR1 -x xinetd`), it will dump state information to `/var/run/xinetd.dump`.